# PHP request isn't get value

Tags: php, get, slider

I have a slider which one is in a  tag. I want to put the slider's to a database.
In the "index.php":

```
<form class="" action="insert.php" method="$_POST">
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5" class="slider" id="myRange" name="myrange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <button id="btn1">Click Here</button>
</form>
```

and in the insert.php:

```
    <?php
$getRangeValue = $_GET['myRange'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","passwd","table_name");
//
// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

$mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO ertekek (RangeValue, anotherValue) VALUES ($getRangeValue, 11)");
echo "New record has id: " . $mysqli -> insert_id;
$mysqli -> close();
?>
```

The url: "http://localhost/insert.php?myrange=10"

Its running, and it generate a row, but the row is totaly empty... so i don't know what's going on...

Comment: You are very confused, you are launching a form with a `POST` method pretending to use the `GET` method on a link that will never be what you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code:

```
<form class="" action="insert.php" method="POST">
   <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5" class="slider" id="myRange" name="myrange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <button id="btn1">Click Here</button>
</form>
```

and in the insert.php:

```
<?php
$getRangeValue = $_POST['myrange'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","passwd","table_name");
//
// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

$query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ertekek (RangeValue, anotherValue) VALUES (?, 11)");
$query->bind_param('i',$getRangeValue);
$query->execute();
echo "New record has id: " . $mysqli -> insert_id;
$mysqli -> close();
?>
```

**What have I changed?**

- I changed the method `method="POST"` instead of `method="$_POST"`
- Change `GET` to `POST` on variable `$getRangeValue`
- Using prepare statment instead of simple and not secure query

**Link that I recommend you to read**

- [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get#:%7E:text=GET%20requests%20expose%20parameters%20to,be%20of%20almost%20any%20length.)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)